# Подскажите пожалуйста как можно создать такой компанент

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно создать такую оранжевую тень и векторную фигуру как на картинке html + css
[image: пример]

Answer (score 0):

Векторную фигуру не разглядел... Чтобы сделать тень на CSS используют:

```
box-shadow: x y radius rgb;
```

где х - смещение по координате х
у - смещение по координате у
radius - радиус размытия(необязательно, по умолчанию не размывает)
rgb - цвет тени(по умолчанию черная)

конкретно в твоем примере можно написать примерно так:

```
box-shadow: -10px 15px rgb(255, 188, 45);
```

поподробнее можно почитать об этом по ссылке ниже:
http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-shadow

Comment: Я про фигуру где Best Coffee Flavor которая наложена на картинку, можно ли сделать её при помощи css и где это посмотреть.

Comment: ух, тема сложная для меня, если честно, особо не вникал. Но, вроде, такое делается с помощью тега <svg> и последующим рисованием в векторе. текст поверх картинки могу только с помощью костылей напихать. О том, что такое <svg> можно почитать на хабре, ниже ссылку дам, а дальше, если честно, я не настолько прошареный :(
https://habr.com/ru/company/simbirsoft/blog/332750/

Comment: я нашел свойство clip-path